# Regex optional group fails whole search

Tags: .net, regex, quantifiers

I'm stuck with something obvious which I can't make working:

There is a text like: "`.... blah-blah-blah... Grupper blah-blah-blah Butik ...`".
`Grupper` is an optional token - can be omitted in text and Butik - is mandatory. So it should match `Grupper` if there is one and `Butik` always.

Expression like `(Grupper)?[\s\S]*?(Butik)` never catches `Grupper`, but without ? works fine (and fails completely, of course, when there are no 'Grupper' in original text).

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(Grupper)?` matches Grupper if it appears **0 or 1** times. So it matches something, even if Grupper isn't part of it.

If your string starts with Grupper, the backreference `(Grupper)` will contain it (Regular Expressions are greedy by default), and if the string doesn't start with Grupper, the backreference will be empty.

In your place, I would catch Butik and Grupper in 2 different regular expressions.

Comment: `Grupper?` matches either `Grupper` or `Gruppe`.

Comment: Well, thanks, separate regex working ok.